# How to get commit hash in git show-branch?

Tags: git

```sh
git show-branch branchX branchY
```

**Output Format:**

```sh
+  [branchX~1] Commit Message Here
```

This shows the relative count from the tip commit of `branchX`. Is there any way to include the corresponding commit hash (short or long) too? I referred the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch) but was unable to find anything.

*PS: I have many commits on the output list, so I don't prefer to check in logs one by one.*

Comment: `git rev-parse branchX~1`

Comment: Minor but noteworthy: `branchX~1` is the relative count from `branchX`, not from `HEAD`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch) link itself which has been mentioned.

`--sha1-name` does the trick.

**Sol**:

```sh
git show-branch --sha1-name branchX branchY
```

**Output**:

```sh
+  [COMMIT-HASH] Commit Message Here
```

Comment: This is way simpler than my solution! (though slightly less tweakable) Thanks for the exposure to a git command I never heard of since more than a year of learning git ^^ This one (`show-branch`) and its buddy `show-ref` I stumbled upon while researching the other.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks for your answer too. Just felt like digging more into the docs again in case I missed anything. Alas, found it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) and benefit from its formatting options, like this

```
git for-each-ref --format="[%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)] %(objectname:short) %(contents)" refs/heads/<branchName>
```

Example output :

```
[master [ahead 1]] e1c8aad Commit message here
```

This is for one branch `<branchName>`, but for the branches list in this format, just replace `refs/heads/<branchName>` with `refs/heads/`